# Why do I get FormatException with NLog?

Tags: c#, nlog, formatexception, nlog-configuration

I get the fllowing in the internal NLog log :

```
2020-05-10 16:38:09.9251 Warn Error when formatting a message. Exception: System.FormatException: The input string had an incorrect format.
   vid System.Text.StringBuilder.FormatError()
   vid System.Text.StringBuilder.AppendFormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider, String format, ParamsArray args)
   vid System.String.FormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider, String format, ParamsArray args)
   vid System.String.Format(IFormatProvider provider, String format, Object[] args)
   vid NLog.LogEventInfo.CalcFormattedMessage()
```

If fill the LogEventInfo like this :

```
var logEvent = new LogEventInfo();
                    logEvent.Level = logData.LogLevel.ToLogLevel();
                    logEvent.Message = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(logData, Formatting.Indented);
                    logEvent.Properties.Add("logdata", logData);
                    logEvent.Parameters = new object[1] { logData };
                    _genLogger.Log(logEvent);
```

The warning seems to come from when I set the Message to this :

```
{
  "ComputerName": null,
  "LogLevel": 5,
  "LogId": null,
  "PersonId": null,
  "Text": "Communication Message",
  "TimeStamp": "2020-05-10T16:42:55.9456429+02:00",
  "ExceptionTyp": 7,
  "UserMessage": null,
  "RelatedObjectJsonString": "[\r\n  {\r\n    \"Address\": \"https://192.168.130.29:44476/MyApp5Service/Client\",\r\n    \"IsEmpty\": false,\r\n    \"IsFaulted\": false,\r\n    \"Action\": \"GetUserConfigurations\",\r\n    \"CallDirection\": 0,\r\n    \"EventTime\": \"2020-05-10T16:42:55.9406583+02:00\",\r\n    \"IsCallback\": false\r\n  }\r\n]",
  "SystemInformation": ""
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Regards

Comment: What's the idea here? Why is the logdata in the message, parameters and properties? I think it should be in one at most.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message is string-formatted or structured-formatted message. The parameters are used for formatting the message.

### Examples

#### String-formatted

When all template holders are numeric (between the `{` and `}`), the message is used as a string-formatted message.

```
logger.Info("Logon by user:{0} from ip_address:{1}", "Kenny", "127.0.0.1");
```

Where the first parameter is the *message* and the others the *parameters*

#### Structured format:

```
logger.Info("Logon by {user} from {ip_address}", "Kenny", "127.0.0.1"); // Logon by "Kenny" from "127.0.0.1"
```

### Current issue

So we're doing here something like:

```cs
string.Format("{
  "ComputerName": null,
  "LogLevel": 5,
  "LogId": null,
  "PersonId": null,
  "Text": "Communication Message",
  "TimeStamp": "2020-05-10T16:42:55.9456429+02:00",
  "ExceptionTyp": 7,
  "UserMessage": null,
  "RelatedObjectJsonString": "[\r\n  {\r\n    \"Address\": \"https://192.168.130.29:44476/MyApp5Service/Client\",\r\n    \"IsEmpty\": false,\r\n    \"IsFaulted\": false,\r\n    \"Action\": \"GetUserConfigurations\",\r\n    \"CallDirection\": 0,\r\n    \"EventTime\": \"2020-05-10T16:42:55.9406583+02:00\",\r\n    \"IsCallback\": false\r\n  }\r\n]",
  "SystemInformation": ""
}", logData);
```

Don't think that is what you need ;)

### Solution

I'm not sure if you need the data in your message. So listed both options.

There is no need to JSON convert the data yourself. That could be done in the config.

#### Data in message

I would recommend to use structured logging here.

```
logger.Log(loglevel, "Message with {LogData}", logData);
```

You could render the logData as JSON as follows in your config:

```
${event-properties:item=LogData:jsonEncode=true}
```

See [${json-encode}](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Json-Encode-Layout-Renderer) and [${event-properties}](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/EventProperties-Layout-Renderer)

Note: you have some control how the message (`${message}`) will be rendered, see [How to use structured logging](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/How-to-use-structured-logging)

#### Data not in message

Use the `.WithProperty`, which is syntactic sugar for the *properties*.

```
logger.WithProperty("LogData", logData).Log(loglevel, "Message without LogData");
```

Also here you could render the object as JSON with the `${event-properties:item=LogData:jsonEncode=true}`

Comment: Thanks, I have a custom LogToServiceTarget where I "unpack" my data from LogEventInfo and sends it to the server where it will be logged to a database. So this case I only use the message as a mean to transport my data object that will be sent to the service. What would be the best solution for this to avoid these warnings?

Comment: You can't use the message for that. The message *will* be parsed (upon request) and is really not designed for that. Please use LogEventInfo properties for that and not the message.